# PhantomJSDriverService not recognized by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to utilize phantoJS to run my selenium test in a headless mode. For that I am doing following,

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);                        
            caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                    "path/to/your/phantomjs.exe"
                );
```

For some reason PhantomJSDriverService is underlined as an error in eclipse. I am not able to call PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY using dot notation from PhantomJSDriverService.

What might I be doing wrong? Will explain more if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `For some reason PhantomJSDriverService is underlined as an error in eclipse` Eclipse tells you what is wrong, Hover the error icon on the left of the editor and check the message like [shown in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlTNx.png)

Comment: Do you have phantomjsdriver.jar in your build path?

Comment: Error message says "PhantomJSDriverService cannot be resolved to a variable"

@Grasshopper, I don't think we are required to put phantomjsdriver.jar in the build path. I am providing the location of phantomjs.exe in the following line

caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
                    "path/to/your/phantomjs.exe"
                );

Comment: @Grasshopper, Yep you are right I do need jar file also :) I didn't realize that before :) 

Used this in my pom.xml file.

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/phantomjsdriver -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
   <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: How do I accept your answer?

Comment: I put it as an answer below... u can accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have phantomjsdriver in your build path. Get the latest version...